Swagger springdoc-openapi-ui dependency throwing 'Not Found' error
I am working on a Spring project 5.3 version (not spring boot)  with Java 11 and I tried to include springdoc-openapi-ui dependency and created an OpenApiConfig class and this project uses spring security too so I extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to permit swagger URL.
Below is my pom dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>

But when I try to hit the URL after these changes, I am getting 'Not Found' on the page.
I have tried these URL among others:

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html

Any pointers to help me fix this would be appreciated.
I wanted to see the swagger page opened upon hitting the URL but I got 'Not Found' error.

Did you try without .html in the web browser?

@YAS_Bangamuwage yes, I have tried without the .html in the browser. Did not work for me.
